# How to dispatch a stack action from another tab?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

My app has two tabs and one of the tabs has a stack navigator inside. How can I dispatch a poptotop action for this stack from the other tab.
I've tried:

```
navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
```

From the other tab, but I get this error:

> The action 'POP_TO_TOP' was not handled by any navigator.
>
> Is there any screen to go back to?

Which is logical because the tab I'm dispatching it from has no stacks. I've been searching the net to find a way to link this command to its relative tab, but no success.

Comment: What do you want to happen as a result of this command?

Comment: I want all open stack screens to be closed and only the top one to be shown which is what poptotop supposed to do. It saves memory and improves performance.

Comment: Just navigate back to the screen you want to go to. React Navigation will unmount the other screens for you.

Comment: Sadly the issue will not go on its own. The app becomes slow after navigating to more than five screens and never recovers unless I press the tab button which by default, does a poptotop action. I want to dispatch this action each time the user presses the respective button that navigates to any stack screen.

Comment: React Navigation is not the issue here - having a five-screen limit would make it unusable for all but the simplest apps. I've never felt this limit and have worked on apps with 30+ screens in the nav stack. Make sure you're using cleanup functions in your useEffect calls and check any long-running processes you've started - listeners etc. Log out how often suspicious functions are running. There's likely an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: "I've never felt this limit and have worked on apps with 30+ screens in the nav stack"
with a low-end device such as mine?

Comment: yes, these apps have had QA processes that include legacy devices

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem anyway with a trick using redux.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question with your solution, it may help future visitors!

Comment: Not sure if I should, it doesn't answer the question, it's just a trick that happens to work.